# How to share Internet both via wire and Wi-Fi?

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, ethernet, ics

I try to convert Windows 7 computer to router. I can create Wi-Fi hotspot via `netsh` and share Internet via this Wi-Fi.
I also can share Internet with wired connection.

But how to do that simultaneously?
So:

1. One Ethernet adapter is used to connect to Internet.
2. Another Ethernet adapter is used to share Internet connection with another computer.
3. I created Wi-Fi hotspot, but I can not share Internet via this hotspot, because when I right click Internet connection, it doesn't allow to share with 2 networks. I can not also create network bridge between hosted virtual Wi-Fi and Ethernet; when I create bridge between real Wi-Fi and Ethernet, virtual hotspot doesn't follow these settings.
   So, are any ideas how to force Windows 7 computer to share Internet both wirelessly and via wire?

Comment: Were you able to achieve the above config?

Comment: No, I wasn't. It is possible to use vmware, however, vmware means  another OS installation, spending a lot of memory and disk space, so this solution is not very useful. Linux is really much better software router.

Answer (score 0):

> So, are any ideas how to force Windows 7 computer to share Internet both wirelessly and via wire?

I would not suggest you using Windows 7 as a software router. The ICS is a limited NAT component. Windows 7 doesn't support acting as a software router by default. You need some routing software to achieve your goal.

Besides, any Linux distribution can easily achieve your goal by configuring the iptables.

Comment: Linux distributions common problems are drivers. It is primarily desktop computer that needs to share Internet to limited devices, Wi-Fi adapter is USB one which is problematic for Linux. So, in my current configuration the cheapest solution is Windows; of course if I buy powerful router it will work better.